# how to use jquery callback to display a loading circle within flask app

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to trigger a loading page when a submit button is clicked in a `<form>`. At the moment, the loading circle goes on to infinity. I'm not sure how to get the flask route to 'switch off' the loading screen when it completes its process. The result of the flask function is a list. I'm new to ajax/jQuery and require some assistance. This is what I have so far:

**ajax**

```
$(function() {
  $('submit-button').click(function() {
  const lockModal = $("#lock-modal");
  const loadingCircle = $("#loading-circle");
  const form = $("#form-subsrch");

   e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting

    // lock down the form
    lockModal.css("display", "block");
    loadingCircle.css("display", "block");

   $.ajax({
      url:'/smrtsrch/',
      data: $('form-subsrch').serialize(),
      type:'POST',
      success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         lockModal.css('display','none');
         loadingCircle.css('display','none');
      },
      error: function(error){
         console.log(error);
         }
       });
    });
 });
```

**flask**

```
@app.route('/smrtsrch/',methods=['POST'])
def smrtsrch():
    try:
        gc.collect()
        if request.method=='POST':
            query = request.form['smrtsrch']
            return render_template('dplysubsrch.html',svgoutput=smrtSrch(query),query=query)
    except Exception as e: 
        error = f'Problem child - ({e})'
        return render_template('dplysubsrch.html',svgoutput=error)
```

**html**

```
<form id='form-subsrch' method='post' action="{{ url_for('smrtsrch') }}" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <p>
   <br>
      <strong>SMARTS string: </strong>{{query}}
   </p>
   <textarea id='form-text' name="smrtsrch" cols="50" rows="5" required>cccccc=c</textarea> 
   <input id='form-text' class="submit-button" type ='submit'>
   <div id="lock-modal"></div>
   <div id="loading-circle"></div>

<div id="table-results">
   <!-- stuff to make table -->
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#lock-modal {
  display:none;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

#loading-circle {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 4px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-top: 4px solid #3498db;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation: spin 0.6s ease-in infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: is something being shown in browser console after submitting the form and if so could you show a screenshot of it

Comment: right now it just shows the dark screen with loading circle. It doesn't load the `<table>`. I'm not sure if I am writing the right lines of code for the ajax call.

Comment: add a screenshot of browser console after pressing the submit button

Comment: I added the screenshot. The loading circle goes to infinity; there seems to be no error listed in console.

Comment: i realized the `loadingCircle.css('display','block');` was within the `ajax` call; it should have been 'none'. Somehow it got changed. However the `<table>` still does not show. Does it deal with the `data` argument? Without the jquery/ajax call, the table shows however no loading circle.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your jquery code to:

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit-button').on('submit', function(e) {
        const lockModal = $("#lock-modal");
        const loadingCircle = $("#loading-circle");
        const form = $("#form-subsrch");

        e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting

        // lock down the form
        lockModal.css("display", "block");
        loadingCircle.css("display", "block");

        $.ajax({
            url:'/smrtsrch/',
            data: form.serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                // lockModal.css("display", "block");
                lockModal.parent().remove();
                // loadingCircle.css("display", "block");
                loadingCircle.parent().remove();
                console.log(response);
                $('#table-results').html(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And your HTML to:

```
<form id='form-subsrch' method='post' action="{{ url_for('smrtsrch') }}">
    <p>
        <strong>SMARTS string: </strong>{{query}}
    </p>
    <textarea id='form-text' name="smrtsrch" cols="50" rows="5" required>cccccc=c</textarea> 
    <input id='form-text' class="submit-button" type ='submit'>
</form>
<div id="lock-modal"></div>
<div id="loading-circle"></div>
<div id="table-results"></div>
```

Comment: The table now shows, but for some reason the loading circle never appears or disappears. It just looks as if I don't have a ajax call for the loading circle.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh what do you mean the loading circle never appears or disappears?

Comment: it seems that the `<div id='lock-modal'></div>` and `<div id='loading-circle'></div>` aren't being rendered. When i click 'submit' it just silently loads the table, there is no loading circle being shown.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh where is the image located that is supposed to be loaded in the `<div id='loading-circle'></div>`

Comment: Hi @kellymandem, I am using CSS to generate the loading circle. I have added the CSS above.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh I have edited my answer, hope it that helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188624/discussion-between-spencer-trinh-and-kellymandem).